How to add Drupal 11 support to a module with branches supporting Drupal 8 and 9?
Due to some circumstances, I’ve temporarily taken on the responsibility of supporting our company’s Drupal plugin. However, I have no prior experience with PHP development, nor am I familiar with the Drupal ecosystem. Unfortunately, I’m the one tasked with adding Drupal 11 support for our plugin.
GIVEN

The module has two release branches (7.x-1.x and 8.x-1.x).
Based on the tags, new features have only been added to the 8.x-1.x branch. So, while version 7 is still supported, it doesn’t receive new updates.
Currently, the *info.yml in the 8.x-1.x branch contains core: 8.x and core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9 || ^10, which suggests that the plugin supports versions 8, 9, and 10.
To add support for version 11, I need to add accessCheck(FALSE) in several places (ref: Access checking must be explicitly specified).
However, this function is only available starting from Drupal version 9.2.

QUESTIONS

Am I correct in assuming that I need to update *info.yml to core: >=9.2 and core_version_requirement: >=9.2 || ^10 || ^11? If so, what should I do about clients still using Drupal 8?
What is the recommended practice in the Drupal community: should I create a new release branch when updating core_version_requirement to >=9.2?

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

For what it’s worth, Drupal 8 and 9 are end-of-life so any obligation you feel to support them is your decision.

QueryInterface::accessCheck() was added in Drupal 8, not Drupal 9.2 (the ability to not call it without an exception being thrown was deprecated in 9.2). A constraint of ^8 || ^9 || ^10 || ^11 sounds like it would cover all your use-cases without further changes

As @Clive said, Drupal 8 also has QueryInterface::accessCheck(), so you do not need to raise the minimum to 9.2 unless you are making other changes.
If your module is hosted on Drupal.org, your module will have an issue queue at https://www.drupal.org/project/MY_MODULE_MACHINE_NAME/issues/.
The Drupal community has an automated bot that generates merge requests to fix known deprecations when a new major Drupal release occurs. These are posted as issues with a title in the following format: Automated Drupal 11 compatibility fixes for MY_MODULE_MACHINE_NAME.  (example of such an issue for the 2.x branch of the Sodium module)
You can search your module's issue queue for such an issue and check the changes that the bot has identified.  This is not guaranteed to be 100% accurate, but it is a good start and, depending on the complexity of the module, may be sufficient.
Should you create a new branch
If you are only adding support for a major version of Drupal (11 in this case), then you do not need to create a new branch; you can create a new release on the current branch.

If you drop support for clients or remove or change API in a way that could break clients, you make a major release. So that means a new release branch where the first number increases.
In short: breaking changes are in major releases.

This is somewhat incorrect: Dropping support for old versions is NOT a breaking change and should not increase the major version number. This is what composer / semver was made for.

If module v1.0 supports core:^8 || core:^9 || core:^10, and the next module version supports core:^9 || core:^10 || core:^11 (and there are no public API changes), then do NOT make a new major version. This is just unncecessary work for site owners. Composer can and should handle this. Core's QueryInterface::accessCheck() is safely covered through composer's dependency constraints.

@Hudri , in that case, does it mean that if I decide to raise the minimum core version, I can still continue with the 8.x-1.x release branch and simply add the next sequential tag, such as 8.x-1.5?

If you do not make a major version in this case, you can never again make feature releases for older core versions. That's semver. If you have, say 1.1.x and drop support for old core version in, say 1.2.x, you cannot ever release 1.3.x, a minor release with new features, for the older core versions. That may be fine for your use case but you should be aware of that fact.

True, but IMHO not really a problem: You still can release a new bugfix version 1.1.whatever, even after 1.2.0 exists.

Of course that is true—for bug fix releases. But with feature releases in semver you have to change the second number, which in your plan, you cannot do.
